# Calculating intersection between points and polygon in shapefile

Tags: python, shapely, fiona

I want accomplish the following using command line python tools only (shapely + fiona)

I was wondering if there was a straightforward way for me to do the following:

1. Read in a shapefile (all counties in the UK)
2. Read in a csv with a list of lat / lon (this I know how to do)
3. Spit out a csv with the same list of points and the polygon id from
   the shapefile, indicating that the point lies within the polygon (i.e.
   in the county)

Ive got this to work by manually constructing polygons from a csv
export of the shapefile, but I'm afraid that Im not going to deal very
well with holes in counties, or edge cases. A standard out-of-the-box
solution would be great.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: A simple Google search reveals [GIS with Python, Shapely, and Fiona](http://macwright.org/2012/10/31/gis-with-python-shapely-fiona.html), and others...

Answer (score 1):

The **Shapely** method [object.within(other)](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.within) looks tailored for your purpose.

You may also be interested in [object.touches(other)](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.touches).